# Why my cursor is always null?

Tags: android

Following code I use to get images from gallery

```
final Uri sourceUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader( this,sourceUri,null,null,null,MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE );
Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
```

here cursor fetches all the images  but when I give a specific path as uri like below

```
String dirUri = "/storage/emulated/myimages";
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query( Uri.parse(dirUri),  null, null, null, null );
```

then cursor always gets null value.

How to resolve this ?

Comment: Try out the path as `"content://media/external/images/media"`

Comment: @GrIsHu, but then will give me all images, I want images from particular path only.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead of your code:

```
 File images = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                        + "/myimages");


    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query( Uri.parse(images.toString()),  null, null, null, null );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below to get the image from particular folder.

```
String dirUri =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/myimages";
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(new File(dirUri).toString()),  null, null, null, null );
```